# get the version of an installed file

Tags: version, nsis

I would like display in section description the version of an executable installed bu the setup?

```
LangString DESC_SecSoftware ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Software PX"
!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${DescText} "Software test"       
!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END
```

How read the file version of test.exe ?

It is possible to read file version like this :

```
${GetFileVersion} "C:\ftp\programm.exe" $ProgramVersion
```

with `!include "FileFunc.nsh"`

but the path must be absolute. I don't manage to read the fileVersion whitch is contained in the install.

Answer (score 7):

the `${GetFileVersion}` macro will let you read a file version **at runtime** on the machine where you are performing the installation, and where the file is certainly not present outside of the installer .exe

Instead, you can use `GetDllVersionLocal` that is executed **at compile time** and will get the version from the original .exe present on the programmer host.

```
!include "logiclib.nsh"
ShowInstDetails show
OutFile "exeversion.exe"

!define exe_to_read "some.exe"

Section

    DetailPrint "getting version $EXEPATH"
    GetDllVersionLocal "${exe_to_read}" $R0 $R1 ;the two values were read during compilation

    IntOp $R2 $R0 / 0x00010000
    IntOp $R3 $R0 & 0x0000FFFF
    IntOp $R4 $R1 / 0x00010000
    IntOp $R5 $R1 & 0x0000FFFF
    StrCpy $0 "$R2.$R3.$R4.$R5"
    DetailPrint "version read: $0"

SectionEnd
```